# adding text over images

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

How can I add text over images on wordpress. I am using the `Sydney` theme and in the customization area and using the wp display images plugin , I managed to assign a single image per each page, is there anyway that I can also add text over these images?

I dont have access to the editor on the appearance section. is not possible to add this text to the images using just the CSS?

Comment: can you post your code here?

Comment: @vel, I remember I talked to u yesterday and I told u that I dont have access to my code, is there another way, like by adding custom css and and adding text over each image that I want?

Comment: you can visit https://www.haagsehof.nl/, and see the website I have to have text on all pages expect FRONT PAGE and CONTACT page.

Comment: which image you want to `adding text over images`?

Comment: @vel the header image u see on the pages : Onze Klanten/Werken bij/Wie zijn wij.  these pages have an image that needs to ahve a text over them , its just 2 words

Comment: install these plugins https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7C61.png

Comment: @vel I ahve them both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code for displaying image below the header. You need to modify this code if you want add a text. Without changing this code you do cannot do.

Are you able to see the code in editor in admin panel?

```
    <div class="sydney-hero-area">
        <?php sydney_slider_template(); ?>
        <div class="header-image">
            <?php sydney_header_overlay(); ?>
            <img class="header-inner" src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo esc_attr( get_custom_header()->width ); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">
        </div>
        <?php sydney_header_video(); ?>

        <?php do_action('sydney_inside_hero'); ?>
    </div>
```

Try this style

```
.page-id-10 .header-image:before {
    content: 'onze-klanten';   
}

.page-id-8 .header-image:before {
    content: 'werken-bij';   
}
.page-id-206 .header-image:before {
    content: 'Wie zijn wij';   
}


.header-image:before {  
    display: block;
    padding-top: 25%;
    font-size: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

.header-image {   
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: no for some reason, I dont have access to the editor on the appearance section. is not possible to add this text to the images using just the CSS?

Comment: yes it worked fine. however every page now has this text "teste", is there anyway that we can put unique texts on top of each image?

Comment: thansk alot, this worked. Can you also help me with this, if u make the website small, the css of the front page will be totally screwed for the mobile version is there anyway I can fix that>

Comment: You have to use media query in css.

Comment: can you explain to me how?, also I want the cotact button to open a modal, how can I do that?

Comment: `I want the cotact button to open a modal` you cant do with css.

Comment: can you explain to me how this words I dont get this.

Comment: You can't do with css

Comment: how can I do this then ?

Comment: You have to change in code. You need to access files

Comment: I can access them via the cpnale now, btw my css id different at every browser how can I fix that?

Comment: What is different?